# ejabberd PostgreSQL chat persistence table

Tags: database, postgresql, xmpp, ejabberd

I am using the `odbc` auth_method in my ejabberd and using postgres as my database. I need to see the chat history (messages) made between two users in my database.

## Followed these steps:

1) CREATEDB myejabberd;

2) psql myejabberd < /path/to/my/pg.sql

3) CREATE USER ejabberduser;

4) I commented the `auth_method: odbc` and enabled `auth_method: odbc`.

5) For ODBC configuration, to use postgres i enabled this

`odbc_type: pgsql
odbc_server: "localhost"
odbc_database: "myejabberd"
odbc_username: "ejabberduser"
odbc_password: "ejabberd"`

6) I tried to run the admin `http://localhost:5280/admin`. It works fine and I made some between two users using the Adium.

I can see the registered users in the `users` table but i cant able to find out the table where the chat history be stored.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a default, message history are not stored in the database.

You may want to look into the Message Archive Management (XEP-0313, aka MAM) XMPP extension, supported in [ejabberd 15.06](https://blog.process-one.net/ejabberd-15-06/).

You can use the [mod_mam (Message Archive Management - XEP-0313)](http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/configuration/#modmam) module. It works perfect. And dont forget the add the default option as `always` or `roster`. By default its `never`

Comment: Hey Mickael, I check the modules_available in my terminal. It shows the ejabberd_mod_mam module. I tried to install it but it is not getting install. Is there anything i have to do ??

Comment: it is already provided in ejabberd 15.06. You should download and use that version.

Comment: Thanks mickeal, `mod_mam` works for me and I forget to add default ** default: always ** option to that. Now works great :) And also I am editing your answer with some lines